# Python - why does my short code not work?

Tags: python

why does the following code not work? I have a list of words and want to detect these words in an example sentence.

```
Sentence = 'This could be a sentence'

with open('Badwords_conjunctive.txt') as file:
    if any(word in Sentence for word in file.readlines()):
        print('Conjunctive should rather be avoided')
```

Badwords_conjunctive.txt is a textfile with the following text:

```
could
might
may
ought
should
Would
```

All it does is '[Finished in 0.3s]' - Shouldn't it trigger the print statement as the word 'could' is in the example sentence?

Grateful for all tips

Comment: `any(word.strip() in Sentence for word in file.readlines())`. Each elements from readlines is appended with a `\n`, hence no matches.

Comment: Try breaking down the code into a loop instead of using any. Print out all the values you are comparing and see if you can see what the problems are.

Comment: Jesus, thank you thats it! any(word.strip() solved it

Comment: @Paul Rooney - how would that loop look like? Pythonnoob here

Comment: @Adrian_G it might look something like [this](https://ideone.com/lkLfXc). Its equivalent code (except my code doesn't stop (short circuit) when it finds a match). Iy will show the two key problems in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "any" term above looks incorrectly formed. Try this:

```
Sentence = 'This could be a sentence'
with open('Badwords_conjunctive.txt') as file:
    for word in file.readlines():
        if word.strip() in Sentence.split():
             print('Conjunctive should rather be avoided')
```

Comment: What is the count variable for?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally left in - I've just removed it

Answer (score 0):

Your words contain a "\n" character that is why it does not match with your sentence. You should remove the "\n" before comparing:

```
Sentence = 'This could be a sentence'

with open('Badwords_conjunctive.txt') as file:
    if any(word.strip() in Sentence for word in file.readlines()):
        print('Conjunctive should rather be avoided')
```

Comment: May I ask, why did you change it from 'any' to 'all'

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, it should be any

Comment: Don't use replace (and most certainly not "raplace"... ;)) for this, use strip().